# Changing a word document title with Textbox values

Tags: vba, ms-word

Im currently making a VBA userform with multiple textboxes. My goal is to make a macro enabled word template that pops up a userform on startup, containing multiple textboxes where the user can input values.

I was looking for a way to change the default save title of my word document. I wanted to pass input values from textboxes into the title so that it would look something like this:

> "Textbox1.Value_Textbox2.Value_Combobox1.Value_Textbox3.Value_....."
>   (Space for the user to personalize the document name)

The underscore seperation is very important.

I tried setting it with

```
   'WORKS'
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSummaryInfo)
    .Title = TextBox7.Value
    .Execute
End With
```

With the aim to combine all those textbox values into textbox 7 but i just cant get it to work. Is there any other way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try this:

```
With Me
    .TextBox7 = Join(Array(.TextBox1.Text, .TextBox2.Text, .ComboBox1.Value, .TextBox3.Text), "_") '<--| list your controls 'name.property' in the desired order
End With

With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSummaryInfo)
    .Title = Me.TextBox7.Text
    .Execute
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i was looking for an array like this. Now i just have to see how i fix the bug where it chops off the rest of the title once it comes across a non-alphanumeric character.

Comment: You are welcome. Should you get stuck with new issues post a new question.